# what does 1 and 2 do in for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, range

```
def odd_indices(lst):

  new_lst = []

  for index in range(1, len(lst), 2):

    new_lst.append(lst[index])

  return new_lst
```

I am trying to make sense of this, but I am not sure what 1 and 2 in the for loop do

Comment: You want us to look up [the `range` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) for you?

Comment: Am in right in thinking that 1 is the starting point and 2 is the number of steps. Then doesnt that mean it would skip a list position each time

Comment: If you can help me make sense of this it would be great and appreciated

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range (a couple of clicks away from the link posted above).

Comment: I have got it now. thank you for your help

Comment: why is my questions downvoted everytime. I am just trying to learn

Comment: @moahiya: For really basic stuff like this, Q&A format just doesn't work; there is a huge baseline *everyone* needs to learn to ask useful questions about a particular language, and that's what [tutorials are for](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html). For simple stuff like this, reading the docs or running a tiny bit of the code in an interactive interpreter (e.g. `>>> list(range(1, 10, 2))`) would have answered your question. To be clear, I didn't downvote, but I can understand why some people would; one of the approved reasons for downvoting is "does not show any research effort".

Comment: I will keep that in mind. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Starting at index 1 (the first odd value)
2. For the length of the list
3. At an interval of 2 (every next odd value)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for range is:

```
range(start, stop, step)
```

The start (1) is where you start looping, the stop is where you stop, and the step (2) is how much you increment each iteration.

The range in your code basically says that you are looping from one to the end of the list on intervals of 2.